# How to get correct date part from variable sql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2000

There is a need to get the **year,month and day** part from a date variable.when fired the below query ,it gives day as 8 and month as 4

```
declare @date1 datetime
set @date1='04/08/2014'
        ------'dd/mm/yyyy' 

--select @date1,year(@date1) year1,month(convert(@date1,datetime)) month1,day(@date1) day1
select   YEAR(CONVERT(DATETIME,@date1)) YEAR1,
            MONTH(CONVERT(DATETIME,@date1)) MOTNH1,
            DAY(CONVERT(DATETIME,@date1)) DAY1
FROM            Tab1
```

Comment: It would be better to use `yyyyMMdd` which SQL server will always interpret unambiguously, if you have control over the formatting. Even better would be to just work with `datetime` values and avoid any consideration of string forms, if possible.

Comment: but,i need to follow the british date format dd/mm/yy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [this](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/SQLDateTimeFormats.aspx) for DateTime possible formats

```
declare @date1 datetime
set @date1=CONVERT(DATETIME,'04/08/2014',103)

SELECT  YEAR(@date1) YEAR1,
        MONTH(@date1) MOTNH1,
        DAY(@date1) DAY1
```

Make a note thar `dd/MM/yyyy` is different than `dd/MM/yy`. The first need `103` as the format switch and the latter needs `3`.

Comment: still gives the month as 4

Comment: Check my edit. It is because you are declaring your variable as DateTime and apply directly the value. If you convert the string representation with the 103 format, you will get the right date.

Comment: The `CONVERT`s within the `SELECT` query are pointless - `@date1` is already a `DATETIME` at this point so they become No-ops.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever So true. I had left them because initially i thought the var was varchar, but yes, they are pointless since it is datetime.

Comment: Also, in SQL Server you don't need the `FROM` clause when getting the values of variables: `Select Year(@date1) Year1, Month(@date1) month1, Day(@date1) day1` will do.

Comment: @Richard It depends on if you want to get the values themselves, or the values for each row of the table.

Comment: No use of the table in this case... nor in the question (I just assumed the questioner had more of an Oracle background).

Comment: @Richard Indeed the `FROM` had actually no point in this case since no other column is used, so i removed it.